# Another notation question: What is $\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0}{}{n}{n-1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, notation

Hi I'm sorry to ask another question so soon but I'm unaware of what the following notation means. Again this is taken from a Combinatorics context.

It looks like this: $\begin{Bmatrix}
n\\ 
n-1
\end{Bmatrix}$

I'm told it is equal to $n\choose 2$

EDIT: The question in hand: Find a number $n>2$ such that n and $\begin{Bmatrix}
n\\ 
n-1
\end{Bmatrix}$ have different parity.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I edited your question, is that OK or is there something else you wanted to write?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what the number $\begin{Bmatrix}
n\\ 
n-1
\end{Bmatrix}$ is supposed to be? Some context will make it much easier.

Comment: 5xum, I have added the full question.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: My apologies. I thought that most people on here would know the answer to the question anyway, so I didn't feel the need to try and target experts in a specific field. Thanks for the link, though. I will make sure to do this in future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be the [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Answer (score 4):

These are Stirling numbers of the second kind and here is a reference to your [relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Simple_identities):

$$\begin{Bmatrix}
n\\ 
n-1
\end{Bmatrix} = {n \choose 2}$$